# ASP MVC WebClient byte array transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I have webapi application, that downloads file from another resource

```
public byte[] DownloadDocumentContent(int id)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    var siteUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"];
    return client.DownloadData(siteUrl);
}
```

Then I receive data in host MVC application like this

```
public byte[] DownloadDocumentContent()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
    return client.DownloadData(webapiURL); 
}
```

and send it as a file to user

```
public ActionResult DownloadDocument(string token)
{
    //...
    byte[] result = DownloadDocumentContent(readRequest.Document.Id);
    return File(result, ContentType, string.Format("{0}.{1}", FileName, FileExtension));
}
```

The problem is that the user receice file with invalid content.
I checked the first byte before sending in api application - it was "80"
and after receiving in MVC application it was "34". What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The first thing I would do is to check the returned information with fiddler or a similar tool to ensure that the web server is not sending an error message as HTML.  If this is not the case you could also see exactly what data is being returned and it might give you a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: I checked data with streamreader and I found, that before sending i have many different symbols like ""PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\0\u0...", but after receiving I have something like ASCII encoded string like ""UEsDBBQAB..."

Comment: I have an action action similar to DownloadDocument that returns a FileResult (for image files) rather than ActionResult...